# Match Regex command to check one and only one occurrence of [+,-,/,*,U,D]

Tags: javascript, python, regex

I have a scenario where i need to identify using match_regex whether the characters given below occurs only once and inputs should not contain any other characters or numbers apart form the given list `[+-/*UD]`. Should treat each as separate characters.

Made up by only one occurrence of `[+,-,/,*,U,D]`

Valid cases:

```
+-/    
-UD    
/-D    
+D/
```

Comment: how much long it can be? always 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [negative look ahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) with [captured group value](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). The following regex will check that each character is following by same or not. Only string with single occurrence will get matched.

```
^(?:([+\-\/*UD])(?!.*\1))+$
```

---

[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/lT1iX7/2)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

---

Check the demo snippet :

```js
function change(ele) {
  var re = /^(?:([+\-\/*UD])(?!.*\1))+$/;
  document.getElementById('out').textContent = re.test(ele.value) ? 'Valid' : 'Not Valid';
}
```

```html
<input type="text" oninput="change(this)" />
<span id="out"></span>
```